# Is it possible to create Android service in the yocto environment?

Tags: android, linux, yocto, android-source, firewall

I want to implement firewall in the Android environment.
In the existing Linux environment, firewall was implemented based on the yocto build system, and I intend to use the yocto environment in AOSP.
How do I create Android service based on the yocto build system? Is there any example to refer to?

Recipe was created using the yocto build system in existing linux environment, and it is also intended to be used for aosp firewall.